# Bound on the MGF of the square of a random variable

Tags: probability, concentration-of-measure

Suppose for a random variable $X$,  one knows that 
$ \mathbb{E}\exp(\lambda^2 X^2) \leq \exp(C \lambda^2)$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and some constant $K$.  I would like to show that the random variable is bounded. It is guaranteed to be subgaussian, but one only needs the convergence of the MGF of $X^2$ around some neighborhood of $0$.  Here, we have something much stronger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $C'>C$ Markov's inequality gives

$$\mathbb P[X^2 \geq C']\leq\frac{\mathbb E\exp(\lambda^2X^2)}{\exp(\lambda^2C')}\leq \exp(\lambda^2(C-C')) \to 0$$
as $\lambda\to\infty.$ Hence $\mathbb P[X^2> C]=0.$